# Passing and returning two different generic classes in method

Tags: c#, generics

Right now I am using `T` for Generic1, but understandably getting an error when I pass in the sPayload because I'm unsure how to specify a second generic type.

```
public static Generic1 SendReceive<Generic1>(string sUrl, Generic2 sPayload)
{
    using(WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        string response = webclient.UploadString(sUrl, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sPayload));
        Generic1 parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Generic1>(response);
        return parsedResponse;
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid using conditional statements and hardcoding the potential types being passed in. I'm just unsure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify both types in the declaration:

```
public static TResult SendReceive<TResult, TPayLoad>(string sUrl, TPayLoad sPayload)
{
    using(WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        string response = webclient.UploadString(sUrl, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sPayload));
        TResult parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(response);
        return parsedResponse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple generic types by separating them with a comma

```
public static TResponse SendReceive<TRequest,TResponse>(string sUrl, TRequest sPayload)
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple parameters using this this way

```
public static T1 SendReceive<T1,T2,...Tn>(string sUrl, TRequest sPayload)
{
   //TODO Code
}
```

and then you can call it like this

```
className.SendResponse<Class1, Class2,...Classn>(...);
```